# Excel 2016. HOw do I make a hyperlink cell into text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, hyperlink

I have a column of text which are all hyperlinks. I want to copy the text and url into seperate fields.

For Example
Cell(A1) has "Apple" (hyperlink to http://www.apple.com)

I want to put the values into D and E

D1 would contain "Apple"

E1 would contain the URL http://www.apple.com

```
Function GetURL(HyperlinkCell As Range)
    GetURL = Replace(HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "file:", "")
End Function
```

I tried this in ThisWorkbook (VBA) and I got the results as **#NAME?** in my spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your function in a **standard module**:

[image]

and then it will work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your code in a normal module:

- Right click your project in the VBE
- Insert: Module
- (Optionally) give your module a more sensible name

Cut/Paste your code there. It should work just fine then!

To make your intentions a bit more clear, you can extend your function header by explicitly declaring it as a `Public` function (not stating it will not change anything, but some people then assume it to be implicitly `Private`) and by setting the return type to `String`:

```
Public Function GetURL(HyperlinkCell As Range) as String
```

As the Hyperlink property only contains strings, there's nothing wrong with making it explicit in your UDF.